# Java - Showing a Webpage In Jframe

Tags: java, html

I have just recently added a update log to my game. I am using tumblr to show the update news. I used simple code (Listed Below) to show it but when I run it it looks nothing like the original tumblr!

```
package javaapplication32;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GetWebPage {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
      JEditorPane website = new JEditorPane("http://smo-gram.tumblr.com/");
      website.setEditable(false);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Google");
      frame.add(new JScrollPane(website));
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.pack();
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not big into web stuff but I think your problem is that you are not retrieving any of the style sheets that make the webpage look nice. I could be completely wrong and I apologize in advance :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few other options available. If you need HTML5 support, switch over to JavaFX (It's way better than Swing IMO). There's also a HTML4/CSS2 renderer available for Swing [called Cobra](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp), and it seems pretty good. Another option would be [Frostwire JWebBrowser](https://github.com/frostwire/frostwire-jwebbrowser), if you don't mind including native code, it seems to give you full HTML5 and CSS3 in Swing.

Answer (score 3):

Check out http://java.dzone.com/articles/web-browser-your-java-swing.

JxBrowser lets you display any webpage,by embedding a browser into your swing application.

Comment: However, it should be noted that JxBrowser is not open source. You should purchase valid license in order to use it in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the call of `pack()` method. In another way, do not expect much of HTML Swing. Supports up to HTML 3.2 (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32.html).

```
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class GetWebPage {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        JEditorPane website = new JEditorPane("http://smo-gram.tumblr.com/");
        website.setEditable(false);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Google");
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(website));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```