# Is there any way to copy contents in Internet explorer window to Jframe application window?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am creating one small executable application using Java and Jframe for a automation project. I just want to copy a particular content from a website(which is opened in Internet Explorer) by clicking a button in Jframe application?

Comment: that is much more than can be simply answered... you can try to check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992547/java-showing-a-webpage-in-jframe

Comment: @ItamarGreen I feel the OP does not want to show the whole page in the JFrame but just wants to copy a portion of the page to the JFrame

Comment: @Blip It's a start. what OP is asking is highly complicated. the HTML of the page must be very specific. I suppose an html parser might be a good way to go about this.

Comment: Do you mean copy/paste functionality, or should your Java-Application directly access IE to select and copy content after your button is clicked?

Comment: Yes, I want java application directly access IE to copy a particular text in a web page. That webpage format is a standard one. But the content of page change for each items fetched from the DB. For Ex, if the page is displaying details of students means, everyone has a different Student ID, but all students have it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Selenium and JSoup. Selenium has code that will allow you to connect a browser to Java(or other languages).  There is a little bit of setup work to get going.
http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ shows there is an Internet Explorer driver.  I use it for Chrome and just today I had to update my chromedriver because it stopped working.  There is code in Selenium for clicking buttons, identifying resources, and getting the web page source.

You can combine Selenium with JSoup.  JSoup is what I am familiar with for getting large sections of HTML out of a web page.  Before I knew about Selenium, I simply used JSoup to download a page's source code and parse it.
https://jsoup.org/

Happy automating.

Comment: Thank you so much.. And Is there any way to copy a word next to a word in selenium? For ex, in a webpage in IE , it shows 'Student ID : XXXXXX'. I just want to copy that 'XXXXXX' alone. Student ID will change for every student details fetched from the database.

Comment: Selenium provides many of the common ways to access HTML elements.  Here is an example that uses XPath.  -- WebElement balance = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"state_bal_val\"]"));--
  String balanceText = balance.getText();  And this link shows what the By class can do.  https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html